# How to export/move a Sharepoint 2013 site

Tags: sharepoint, export, sharepoint-2013

After building a protoype Sharepoint site for the client I am now looking to export it for the client's eyes.

I'm looking for the best solution for exporting, sharing or moving a Sharepoint 2013 site for the client to see on their server. The site is currently only on one server so no server farms are involved.

The site is built using **Sharepoint 2013**.

I've been running through this guide, but could anyopne clarify if this process creates a back-up of the entire site or just the database: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428301(v=office.15).aspx

Any help would be greatly appreciated - Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the custom you've done, anyway you can use backup/restore on Central Admin, otherwise you can use SPBackup-Site and SPRestore-Site from sharepoint PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great video on how to do a backup and restore in SP10.
This does work for SP13 except the backup needs to be done with PowerShell.

[How Do I: Backup and Restore a SharePoint 2010 Site Collection?](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/video/backup-and-restore-a-sharepoint-2010-site-collection.aspx)

The backup and restore is not guaranteed to give you the exact result as some features could be activated and some CSS could change the look of the imported site.